# Writing(in a file) and printing statistics

Tags: c

My task is to create a C program that opens a .c file in which the user then writes some text then said text is printed along with the number of (){}/ and the percentage ratio comments:whole text of the C program.
So far I've this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int k, j, m, n, l, z, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0;
    char str[10000], chh, chhh;
    char ch, file_name[75];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see with extension .c or .txt\n");
    gets_s(file_name);

    fp = fopen_s(file_name, "r");  // reads the file

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        _getche();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name); //prints out the text
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
        str[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    int fsize = i;
    // code above opens up the symbols of the file, code below searches for specific symbols
    int count = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : "); //which symbol to search
    scanf_s("%c", &chh);
    for (i = 0; i < fsize; i++) {
        if (str[i] == chh)
            count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        printf("\nCharacter '%c' is not present", chh); //if there isn't one
    else
        printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", chh, count); //prints their number if there is

    for (k = 0; k<fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '>')
            count1++;  
    }
    for (j = 0; j<fsize; j++) {
        if (str[j] == '<')
            count2++;
    }
    for (m = 0; m<fsize - 1; m++) {
        if (str[m] == '=' && str[m + 1] == '=')
            count3++;
    }
    for (n = 0; n<fsize - 4; n++) {
        if (str[n] == 'e' && str[n + 1] == 'l' && str[n + 2] == 's' && str[n + 3] == 'e') 
            count4++;
    }
    for (l = 0; l<fsize - 2; l++) {
        if (str[l] == 'i' && str[l + 1] == 'f')
            count5++;
    }

    int br;
    br = count4 + count5;
    printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", '>', count1);
    printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", '<', count2);
    printf("\nOccurence of character ==  : %d ", count3);
    printf("\nOccurence of character else : %d ", count4);
    printf("\nOccurence of character if: %d \n", count5);
    printf("\nobsht broi if+else: %d ", br);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out the text inside a file, searches for a specific character you want and prints out its occurrence.

PS: when I try to run it on my PC, Visual Studio spits out a bunch of errors and warnings. I'm puzzled as to how to get rid of them.
[Errors image](https://postimg.org/image/gumsl4ywt/)
Thanks !

Comment: So, what's your problem exactly? When you say Visual Studio is complaining, does that mean you managed to compile it on another system?

Comment: First, all of those "too few arguments" errors should be fixed by calling those functions with the correct arguments.

Comment: And  it looks like you are missing `#include <conio.h>`.

Comment: You can't just replace fopen, gets, scanf and likewise functions with their safe replacements fopen_s, gets_s, scanf_s because those have a different function signature.

Comment: Yes it ran on another system. As for the problem I'm trying to figure out how to mold it to fit my task but I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to figure it out.

Comment: Did you consider passing the file name as a program argument (to your `int main(int argc, char**argv)`  function...)?

Comment: @DavidBowling: `<conio.h>` is not standard C99 (or C11). It is specific to Windows.

Comment: @gEshAdve: your *fix-my-code* question is **off-topic** here. You better work on your homework by yourself. To correct the errors, you'll better read the documentation of the functions you are calling (like [C I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) ...) and spend more time reading about the C programming language.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch-- Agreed. I don't work with Windows myself, but aren't the functions `scanf_s()` and `_getche()` Windows-specific functions found in `conio.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Using GCC I was able to compile this by changing a few methods.

- changed gets_s to gets(file_name) which produces a warning that this is an unsafe function.
- changed _getche() to getchar()
- changed scanf_s() to scanf()
- change fopen_s() to fopen()

This code compiled and ran using GCC on Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int k, j, m, n, l, z, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0;
    char str[10000], chh, chhh;
    char ch, file_name[75];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see with extension .c or .txt\n");
    gets(file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");  // reads the file

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name); //prints out the text
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
        str[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    int fsize = i;
    // code above opens up the symbols of the file, code below searches for specific symbols
    int count = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : "); //which symbol to search
    scanf("%c", &chh);
    for (i = 0; i < fsize; i++) {
        if (str[i] == chh)
            count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        printf("\nCharacter '%c' is not present", chh); //if there isn't one
    else
        printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", chh, count); //prints their number if there is

    for (k = 0; k<fsize; k++) {
        if (str[k] == '>')
            count1++;  
    }
    for (j = 0; j<fsize; j++) {
        if (str[j] == '<')
            count2++;
    }
    for (m = 0; m<fsize - 1; m++) {
        if (str[m] == '=' && str[m + 1] == '=')
            count3++;
    }
    for (n = 0; n<fsize - 4; n++) {
        if (str[n] == 'e' && str[n + 1] == 'l' && str[n + 2] == 's' && str[n + 3] == 'e') 
            count4++;
    }
    for (l = 0; l<fsize - 2; l++) {
        if (str[l] == 'i' && str[l + 1] == 'f')
            count5++;
    }

    int br;
    br = count4 + count5;
    printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", '>', count1);
    printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", '<', count2);
    printf("\nOccurence of character ==  : %d ", count3);
    printf("\nOccurence of character else : %d ", count4);
    printf("\nOccurence of character if: %d \n", count5);
    printf("\nobsht broi if+else: %d \n", br);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gets` is *explicitly* deprecated. And `gcc -Wall -g` would warn you about that.

Comment: This code may work using gcc, but your answer seems to ignore the actual problem with OP's code, i.e., incorrect function calls. Microsoft compilers can be cranky when you try to replace the safe functions such as `scanf_s()` with `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my findings below.

1. gets_s(file_name); -> i dont think this is correct. gets_s Takes up 2 argument and not 1 please use gets instead and try it out or simple scanf to check if it is working.

2._getche() Please use #include header file for that function. Using it would avoid this issue.

3. fopen_s -> Fopen has invalid set of arguments. U need a file pointer as the first argument. Please re-frame the function used. Better go for fopen which has 2 arguments.
4. scanf_s -> has an argument(parameter) where you can specify the buffer size. Hence the above code sacnf_s function u have used is syntaticaly wrong. Please change it accordingly.

Please find the changed code which is commonly used. I have taken the liberty of changing the gets_s to gets, fopen_s to fopen and scanf_s to scanf and have build it. No errors. Please find the code below for your reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
FILE *fp;
int main()
{
int k, j, m, n, l, z, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0;
char str[10000], chh, chhh;
char ch, file_name[75];


printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see with extension .c or .txt\n");
gets(file_name);

fp = fopen(file_name, "r");  // reads the file

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    getchar();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name); //prints out the text
int i = 0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", ch);
    str[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
int fsize = i;
// code above opens up the symbols of the file, code below searches for specific symbols
int count = 0;
printf("\nEnter the character to be searched : "); //which symbol to search
scanf_s("%c", &chh);
for (i = 0; i < fsize; i++) {
    if (str[i] == chh)
        count++;
}

if (count == 0)
    printf("\nCharacter '%c' is not present", chh); //if there isn't one
else
    printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", chh, count); //prints their number if there is

for (k = 0; k<fsize; k++) {
    if (str[k] == '>')
        count1++;
}
for (j = 0; j<fsize; j++) {
    if (str[j] == '<')
        count2++;
}
for (m = 0; m<fsize - 1; m++) {
    if (str[m] == '=' && str[m + 1] == '=')
        count3++;
}
for (n = 0; n<fsize - 4; n++) {
    if (str[n] == 'e' && str[n + 1] == 'l' && str[n + 2] == 's' && str[n + 3] == 'e')
        count4++;
}
for (l = 0; l<fsize - 2; l++) {
    if (str[l] == 'i' && str[l + 1] == 'f')
        count5++;
}

int br;
br = count4 + count5;
printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", '>', count1);
printf("\nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", '<', count2);
printf("\nOccurence of character ==  : %d ", count3);
printf("\nOccurence of character else : %d ", count4);
printf("\nOccurence of character if: %d \n", count5);
printf("\nobsht broi if+else: %d ", br);

fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

At any point of time if u need any assistance please ping me :) Thank you.